# How to set the font size in Eclipse to 10.5?

Tags: eclipse, fonts

Is it possible to use a font size of 10.5 in Eclipse? 10 is too small and 11 is too large, but I am unable to enter 10.5 in the font size dialog, as it requires an integer. Could this setting be changed somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is possible, because the entire SWT Font API uses integer as font heights, and Eclipse builds on SWT.

Comment: Thank you. I found an issue already opened on Eclipse.org. Interested people can vote here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=129314